# Windows Service only partly working

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have created a Windows Service for the very first time. It is not working. The files OnStart.txt and OnStop.txt are created but nothing else happens. I don't believe MSProcess runs. How do I go about troubleshooting?

```
namespace MailScan_Service
{
    public partial class svMaster : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            public svMaster()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MailScan Service");
            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)           
            {
                 System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
                 myTimer.Start();

            }
            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                if (myTimer.Enabled == true)
                    myTimer.Stop();
                System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");
            }

            private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {

                if (!sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
                {
                    MSSettings msSet = new MSSettings();
                    msSet.Load();
                    myTimer.Interval = msSet.ScanTimer * 60000;
                    MSProcess.Start();
                    msSet.Dispose();
                }
            }     
}
```

Yet this simulator works just fine!

```
namespace MailScanSettings
{
    public partial class FormSimService : Form
    {
        public FormSimService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbStatus.Clear();
            tbStatus.Text += "Running";
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer1.Enabled == true)
                timer1.Stop();

            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            tbStatus.Clear();
            tbStatus.Text += "Stopped";
        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            MSSettings msSet = new MSSettings();
            msSet.Load();
            timer1.Interval = msSet.ScanTimer * 60000;            
            MSProcess.Start();
            msSet.Dispose();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't hooked `myTimer.Elapsed` to the event handler anywhere.  So `myTimer_Elapsed` is never going to be called.

Comment: Add a endless While loop in the after myTimer.Start(); in the OnStart Method. Because, after coming into OnStart method, the timer will start and its life will end in the scope of the method and the Elapsed event will never be called. And also you have to add the event Elapsed event to the timer. Also set an interval to the Timer.

Comment: Thanks! I am in the process of binding the timer to the event handler via Visual Studio.

Comment: What kind of timer is it?  I don't think a System.Windows.Forms.Timer will work inside a Windows Service.

Comment: It's a System.Timers.Timer. I should have mentioned that, thanks.

Comment: Haven't gotten it to work yet, still trying!

Comment: Going to write to a log file to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have to debug a lot of Windows Services and have done the same log file pot shot approach.  It's painful and frustrating for sure.

Ultimately I found a tip somewhere, which is that for debugging purposes, you can drop this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

in the beginning of your OnStart method.  It will pop a dialog and ask which debugger you want to attach.  Since you'll already have the solution loaded in Visual Studio, just choose it and it will hit your breakpoints.

It can be tedious as well, but more productive.  You end up in a productivity loop of having to stop the service, uninstall, patch the code, build, reinstall, start, debug...

Comment: FINALLY got it. I put comments into the file and logged them to see how far the program progressed before it blew up. My boss showed me a file that I didn't know about in Visual Studio under Properties called AssemblyInfo.cs. It started working after I added our company name [assembly: AssemblyCompany("Our Company Name Here")] Happy happy joy joy!!